# LINQ optional where clause effect on performance

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I'm fairly confident I have the correct idea, but I need to be certain and wasn't able to come up with the confirmation I needed on my own.

I'm querying a database using Entity Framework with SQL as my backend in C#. Here "testing" is the name of my table.

```
var query1 = from t in testing
             select t;
```

Now I need to add a where clause, but this where clause is optional and controlled by the user. So I add something along the lines of:

```
bool trivialOption = true;
if(trivialOption)
{
    query1 = query1.Where(t => t.TrivialProperty == true);
}
```

This is just one "where" clause that will be applied. There will be more.

To my understanding, as long as I don't enumerate over the list, there is no performance hit in doing it this way, as opposed to doing a completely different query like this:

```
if(trivialOption)
{
    var query1 = from t in testing
                 where (t => t.TrivialProperty)
                 select t;
}
else
{
   var query1 = from t in testing
                select t;
}
```

This, when other optional where clauses are entered in, will get really messy really fast.

Am I correct in saying that lazy/deferred loading allows me to do the first option without any performance hits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct in saying that lazy/deferred loading allows me to do the
>   first option without any performance hits?

Yes. That is correct.

As long as you don't iterate your query using `ToList`, `ToArray` etc. You will not take any performance hits.

You may want to read: [LINQ and Deferred Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/)

Comment: Awesome. Very informative article. Thank you for the reference.